# remove functions and attributes from html code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Let's say we have a div as follows

```html
<div id = "container" >
    <p contenteditable="false">Hello World</p>
    <button onclick="alert();"></button>
</div>
```

and we retrieved the content of the div and saved it into a variable

```js
var content = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML;
```

Now we want to remove the `contenteditable="false"` and the `onclick="alert();"`

I have tried the following:

```js
content = content.replace('contenteditable="false"','');
content = content.replace('onclick="alert();"','');
```

and then put the content back inside

```js
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = content;
```

but this did not work for me.

Comment: Take some time, set jQuery aside and learn what the DOM is. Hint: It's not a string of HTML text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **much** easier to do it by cloning and then removing them from the clone before using `innerHTML`:

```js
var content = cleanContent(document.getElementById("container").cloneNode(true)).innerHTML;
```

Where `clean` is something like:

```
function clean(elm) {
    for (const key in elm) {
        if (key.startsWith("on")) {
            elm.removeAttribute(key);
        }
    }
    elm.contentEditable = false;
    Array.from(elm.children).forEach(clean);
    return elm;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function clean(elm) {
    for (const key in elm) {
        if (key.startsWith("on")) {
            elm.removeAttribute(key);
        }
    }
    elm.contentEditable = false;
    Array.from(elm.children).forEach(clean);
    return elm;
}
var content = clean(document.getElementById("container").cloneNode(true)).innerHTML;
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = content;
```

```html
<div id="container">
<p contenteditable="false">Hello World</p>
<button onclick="alert('x');">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried implementing your code, but i don't know what i am missing can you have a look please [link here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GGWRS9VXWFVN)

Comment: @EliasKhazzaka - There are two problems in that code, one from my answer above and one not. :-) I've updated my answer to use `removeAttribute` instead of `elm[key] = "";` (I thought that worked, experimentation says no, it doesn't -- I haven't used old-style onxyz event handlers in a while!). I also added a live example. The other problem is that your code is running before the elements exist, [details here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element).

Comment: @EliasKhazzaka - Side note: I'd suggest [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) over w3schools (which has had issues with accuracy and completeness) -- and perhaps a good book like [David Flanagan's](https://www.amazon.com//dp/1491952024/).

Answer (score 1):

This does exactly what you want. Get the content of the `container` and remove all the attributes, but as you can see it's a pretty messy solution. I recommend you use `.removeAttr` if the situation allows it. Converting the contents of an entire `div` into string and then replacing attributes with blank space is quite an unusual solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    let content = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML
    let newContent = content.replace(/ contenteditable="false"| onclick="alert|\(|\)|;"/g , '')

    console.log("This is the old content:" + content)
    console.log("This is the new content:" + newContent)

    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = newContent

})
```

Below is a much more simple solution that just removes the attributes when the document is ready, but I don't know if this is quite what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#container").children().removeAttr("contenteditable onclick")

})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what you requested but are you sure you want to have the option the separate the node? You could just target them directly.

```js
const setup = () => {
    const container = document.getElementById("container");
  
  //setup changes
  const content = container.cloneNode(true);
  content.querySelector('p').removeAttribute('contenteditable');
  content.querySelector('button').removeAttribute('onclick');
  
  //apply changes
  container.innerHTML = content.innerHTML;
  }

window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<div id = "container" >
    <p contenteditable="false">Hello World</p>
    <button onclick="alert();"></button>
</div>
```